# What is best practice for Software UI design?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, software-design

The software we are designing allows students to register and participate in different training courses.

When the user logs into the system they get a list of courses they have registered for. They click on the course and then they are redirected to the specific course content.

My question is, what is the best practice upon login if the student is only currently registered for a single course?

Option 1: Just list the single course, but still require the user to click on it before redirecting. Same behavior as if there were multiple courses to select?

Option 2: Upon login, immediately re-direct the user to the specific course content. Save them from having to do the extra click of selecting the course.

Option 3: Open to suggestions...

EDIT: There are no other options available on this page. They register/pay for the courses elsewhere.

Comment: It depends on what the options are on the "post login" page. If the user can register to new training courses from here, it can be a good idea to display this step (Even if it's only for a single course). Mainly in order to make the user "aware" that he could access to other courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any other options on the course selection page other than selecting a course (like registering for another course)? If not, then take them directly to their single course (Option 2). If there are other options, take them to the list and require them to select their course (Option 1).

Comment: @Hunter - My original answer still stands.